# json_encode returns no data

Tags: php, json

The php script below does not return any data. If I use a where clause to limit the data, the script returns data normally. But if I try to select all of the rows (Theres about 1400), nothing gets returned. When I launch the script in my browser, nothing errors, its just a blank page.

```
$conn = new mysqli($serverName, $userName, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) 
{
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM alumni_database.alumni;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    $rows[]=$row;
}

$result->close();
$conn->close();

print(json_encode($rows));
```

SOLVED: The issue was with utf8_encoding. Once I added the line:

```
$conn->query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

The script returned all of the rows.

Comment: If it helps you can try to see if there's an error encoding the $rows with json_last_error()

Comment: and... `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: I tried putting that line in the code, and nothing displayed. I also tried utf8_encode, that didn't work either.

Comment: try also adding after your `print` an `echo json_last_error_msg()`

Comment: After `$result = $conn->query($sql);` add `if ( ! $result ) { echo $conn->error; exit; }`

Comment: I added the lines you suggested, still get nothing but a blank page.

Comment: If I put the "echo json_last_error();" at the end of the script, it echos out the number 5. Any ideas?